# What is the default variable in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

What is the default variable in MATLAB if you do not assign one to an equation? I was thinking it was maybe just `x`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is `ans`, this is also shown in the workspace which contains the variables. Consider this example input in the command line:

```
3*4

ans = 
      12
```

Just be sure never to use `ans` as an actual variable, as that'll mess up your code good.